# $ \frac{x}{\ln x}=\frac{y}{\ln y}=m, \text{to prove } x-y>2\sqrt{\left(m-e\right)\left(3m-e\right)}$

Tags: analysis

\begin{align*}
            \text{for positive real number }&x\text{ and y },\quad x>y\\
            \text{if }\frac{x}{\ln x}&=\frac{y}{\ln y}=m\\
            \text{try to prove }x-y&>2\sqrt{\left(m-e\right)\left(3m-e\right)}\\
\end{align*}

This is one of some kind of problems popular in my senior high (in China), the so-called "extremum-point-shifting problem".

The best way to solve it is definitely to express $ x-y $ by $ m $ , and prove an inequality related to $ 
m $.

But that's really sucky and impossible to actually do so, and we usually try certain algebraic tricks like the ALG-inequality, or we just construct some symmetric function to determine the position relation of $ x $ and $ y $ like $ x>2a-y $, etc.

But here, I've already tried all that I could do, and it turned out to be either an inequality that is way too complex or a hopeless NOVEL AND USELESS attempt.

I'm stuck here.

Any suggestion or solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that $x^y = y^x$.

Comment: This is hard! I guess the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) may be helpful. FWIW, here's a simple parameterization for x & y. Let $x=uy, u>1$. Then $y=u^\frac{1}{u-1}$ and $x=u^\frac{u}{u-1}$ Now let $u=1+1/n$. Then $y=u^n<e<u^{n+1}=x$. But it gets messy when we substitute into that sqrt expression.

Comment: @PM2Ring yep，that’s what I called the complex method, I believe that it is a way but just too sucky.lol, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's always a Good Idea to mention stuff like that in your question. It can make a big difference to whether your question gets up or down votes, or close votes. Also, it helps potential answerers to know what your knowledge level is, and it stops them from wasting space telling you stuff you already know. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for that. I'll try to make it better.:)